# WIN 10 LoadRunner

Tags: windows-10, loadrunner

I have problems with **Http/Html proto with WIN 10**. Recording starts but nothing is recorded. I didn't find materials about it. Does anyone know how to fix?

Ty in advance

Comment: Please use HP LoadRunner 12.53 version.

Answer (score 0):

a) Did it ever work on this machine?

b) Does it work on other machines?

c) If you look to the requirements for your version of LoadRunner, have you explicitly satisfied each and every installation requirement, down to the operating systems supported, the credential levels required and browsers supported? (especially important if (a) is "No!"

Comment: Hi James,  
a) Fresh LR's installation on this machine with WIN10  
b) LR works on other machines with WIN < 10  
c) Credentials and browsers are not a problem.  
One important thing: LR version is 12.02.

Comment: Then you have two paths....you can reconcile the differences between the other machines that are working and this one and/or you can look very particularly at the level of operating system and browser support in a release of LoadRunner which predates the release of your operating system.  LR 12.02 Release date: 12-15-2014.  Win 10 Release date: 07-29-2015.  Never run a test tool on an unsupported platform because you need your test tool performance to be a constant when evaluating an application of unknown quality.  You cannot do that if your test tool is running in an unsupported environment.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows 10** is only supported by **LoadRunner 12.53**, which is the latest generally available version at the moment of posting this answer. Earlier versions are not expected to work properly on this OS.